# No. Of real roots of an equation

Tags: roots

Consider the function

$$ f(x) = 2\cos((x^2+x)/6) - 2^x - 2^{-x}. $$

Clearly $x= 0$ is a root of equation so number of real roots can not be 0 but how to figure out question how many ? From where does this observation start?

Comment: What equation??

Comment: Oops I forgot to write equation but now   u can see .

Comment: Should it be tagged as abstract algebra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rhs is symmetric about y axis and its minimum value is 2. The  graph is increasing on both the sides .  While the maximum of Lhs is $2$ as $-1\leq cos (...)\leq 1$ . Thus  the equation has $1$ real root and that is at $x=0$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  $\cos a \le 1\,$ for any $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}\,$, and $b + \frac{1}{b} \ge 2\,$ for any $\forall b \gt 0\,$ with equality iff $b=1\,$. So:

$$
2 \cos\left(\frac{x^2+x}{6}\right) \;\le\; 2 \;\le\; 2^x + \frac{1}{2^x}
$$

For the equality to hold, both sides must equal $2\,$, therefore $\,b = 2^x = 1\,$, so $\,x=\,\cdots$